# Offline Maps API for C# Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api, maps

I have a C# WPF application which has browser control to display a Google Map.

Google Maps API v3 is being used in the application.

I use data received from a service to plot users current location and history. So a lot of markers and polylines are in use.

But to use Google Maps API, we need to be connected to the internet for sending requests to the server. And I believe that the API wont work offline even with the Enterprise Edition.

I need an alternative to the Google Maps API (preferably open source) to work completely offline, which provide similar services like marking locations, drawing lines, zoom, etc., I don't have lots of time to finish this. So instead of trying out the different available APIs, I was hoping somebody must have done a similar thing so I can finish my task on time. I am currently trying out ArcGIS. Is it good enough for my purpose? Is there an open source alternative?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use this opensource library:

[GMap.NET - Great Maps for Windows Forms & Presentation](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps)

> **GMap.NET** is great and Powerful, Free, cross platform, open source .NET
>   control. Enable use routing, geocoding, directions and maps from
>   Coogle, Yahoo!, Bing, OpenStreetMap, ArcGIS, Pergo, SigPac, Yendux,
>   Mapy.cz, Maps.lt, iKarte.lv, NearMap, OviMap, CloudMade, WikiMapia,
>   MapQuest in Windows Forms & Presentation, supports caching and runs on
>   windows mobile!

It is an opensource library that can do most of your requirements, i forgot to mention that GMap.Net support WPF applications.

And also if you want to use a more advanced library you can try:

[SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap)

> **SharpMap** is an easy-to-use mapping library for use in web and desktop
>   applications. It provides access to many types of GIS data, enables
>   spatial querying of that data, and renders beautiful maps. The engine
>   is written in C# and based on the .Net 4.0 framework. SharpMap is
>   released under GNU Lesser General Public License.

It contains many features like working as a WFS client to load a request data from a standard [OGC Services](http://www.opengeospatial.org/).

Hope my answer help you.

Comment: Does GMap.NET or SharpMap show maps offline?

Comment: Yes, you can cache them on your local computer as a SQLite DB file(s) or you can Store them in MySQL Database.

[GMap.Net Documentaion](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Try to see src sample that demonstrates how to work with google maps: show map control, spatial tree objects, download map, print map, work offline with local cache etc: https://github.com/agafonoff2000/SimpleMap